# C #include errors in VS Code, cannot open libraries

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I use Ubuntu 18.04, VS Code and C/C++ extension and I was trying to test the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68147891/c-graphics-how-to-move-an-object-with-specific-angle) other question but got the following error:

- #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/home/alan/Desktop/C/test/main.c).

Also, it says that it can't open source files from "conio.h" to "iostream.h"...

I tried using vcpkg as VSC suggests but it didn't work :/

The first 3 libraries are okay as always, can anyone help me with the others? Thanks!

```
#include        <stdio.h>
#include         <math.h>
#include       <stdlib.h>
#include        <conio.h>    //Can't
#include     <graphics.h>    //open
#include          <dos.h>    //those
#include     <iostream.h>    //four
```

Comment: All the header you fail to include are old and non-standard, or (old and non-standard) C++ headers. Whatever resource you're using to learn C, throw it away and get a new one. Or better yet, take classes.

Comment: The code looks like it was written for the ancient Borland C++. Getting modern compilers to accept such code will be difficult. Either find a better course/tutorial, or install Borland C++ in Dosbox. If you decide to do the latter, note that you'll be learning an old C++ dialect that has no use today.